# Google Earth 7.3.2: maps not shown

Tags: google

Having installed the latest .deb from Google.
My OS (ubuntu 18.10 64) uses the Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile but everytime I run the Google Earth only the UI is loaded but not the maps.
 How can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: link posted not resolves my issue. I've changed DNS, I've reinstalled the .deb package (with sudo) but without success.
My OS: Xubuntu 18.10, Intel Graphic Integrated, requirements hardware satisfied

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: any suggestions for me? still doesn't work